# Neo4j HA Servers keep failing

Tags: neo4j

We have just put our system into production and we have a lot of users on the production system. Our servers keep failing and we are not sure why. It seems to start with one server then it elects a new master and then a few minutes later all the servers go down in the cluster. I have it setup to send all the writes to the read databases and to leave the writes to the master. I have looked through the logs and cannot seem to find a root cause. Let me know what logs I should upload and or where I should look. Today alone we have had to restart the servers 4 times and it fixes it for a bit but its not a cure for the issue.

All databases are 16GB ram and 8 cpus and SSDs. I have them setup with the following settings in the neo4j.properties

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=6144M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
```

We are using newrelic to monitor the server and we do not see the hardware getting above 50% CPU and 40% memory so we are pretty sure that is not it.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Some basic stuff just in case: are you running a compatible version of Java? Did you set the ulimit? When you say you don't see anything in the logs, are you talking Neo4j logs or system logs? If you build a single DB server in the same environment and stress test the app, does it stay online?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did up the ulimit to the recommended amount. I believe it is 40k. I am about to try exactly what you are recommending. I have also tried switching the settings above back to default and that did not solve the issue either.

Comment: can you post the `neo4j.properties` and `neo4j.server-properties` of all dbs here and also the 30 last lines of the console.log file of each db

Comment: I will be uploading my configs later today but I was able to get the server stable by pulling the system out of HA mode and running it as a single server. We have the same amount of traffic and everything seems to be holding. I also found a query that looks like it was taking a while to run. If all goes well throughout the day I will be putting it back into HA mode and see if it still holds. If it does then the cause had to be the query. If not then it is something much larger.

Comment: Glad you've made some progress. Are you running Neo4j 2.1.5?

Comment: make sure to have `neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M`. 2.1.5 does by error not set a default value for this and therefore assumes 0.

Comment: So another update. We are completely up and running. The issue was a query that was taking 18s to run and since we had high traffic it was causing the databases to get bogged down until they couldn't handle it and they would fail. We do get socket hangups every so often which is next on my list to figure out why but its minor at the moment.

@StefanArmbruster what does that option do? I tried googeling it and did not find anything explaining its significance and what it should be set at. 

Thanks again to everyone who helped me out on this issue and the advice you have given.

Comment: Can you enable GC-logging in neo4j-wrapper.conf and share the GC logs? Also sharing the content of graph.db/messages.log would be good. Also if you could provide some details about your graph model, # of nodes and rels, queries that you run, server config (threads) and a threaddump of an active server it would help. I recommend asking for official Neo Technology support makes most sense as you run in production with Neo4j enterprise.